# How to pass added custom "key=>value" into getCollection()?

Tags: collection, product-collection, magento2.2.4, category-view

On product lisitng page i want to get one more parameter "latitude" for all product,how can i achieve?

Here is my code:-

```
public function setCollection($collection)
    {

        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $mpJoinConditions = 'marketplace_product.mageproduct_id = e.entity_id';

       $this->_collection->getSelect()->join(
                $this->_collection->getTable('marketplace_product'),
                $mpJoinConditions,
                []
            )->columns("marketplace_product.seller_id")->where ("marketplace_product.store_id = '0'");

             echo "<pre>" ; print_r($this->_collection->getData()) ; exit;
}
```

**Note:-As per my requirement,i don't need to create product custom attribute OR use joins.**

I tried to use addData and setData() but didn't get success.

After `print_r()`,added custom `"key=>value"` must be there for each product.

[image]

**Update:-**

By doing following i'm able to do set Latitude seprately and getting the same on phtml file:-

```
  foreach($this->_collection as $key=>$prod_data){

     $prod_data->setData('latitude',$prod_data->getId());    

}
```

I've to sort(DESC) the product based on latitude value,but when i'm printing

```
        echo "<pre>" ; print_r($this->_collection->getData()) ; exit;
```

**then not getting 'latitude' parameter $this->_collection->getData() here due to which i can't apply setOrder()**.on phtml file by using $product->getLatitude() it's showing so please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: would you like to return product from above function array (like displaying) or object?

Comment: thanks for the reply! I want to add in a way so that after doing print_r() "latitude" field added for each product. we've to add this filed for entire product collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the collection and set the data for each item like this:

```
foreach ($this->_collection as $item){
    $item->setData('latitude',1);
}
```

That should give you the required output.

Comment: keep in mind that just doing this will not persist the data in the DB

Comment: The question was not about persisting data or did I miss something?

Comment: you are right. I just wanted to mention this

Comment: @HelgeB thanks for the reply,i already tried but it doesn't work. i've to carry this filed somehere for further calculation.i've to use the same in product sorting.

Comment: @Philip,thanks for the reply! yes,you're right i don't need to save in the table.

Comment: @wakar Ahamad please update the question with the concrete requirement: Adding a fixed field to the collection works as mentioned in the answer, that data can be used everywhere where you use the collection data. "Further calculation" is quite unclear and sorting a collection is again a different thing.

Comment: yes it works... but i need this value in $this->_collection() so that  i can do sorting based on this field...and sorry for my mistake "latitude" can vary for each product.

Comment: OK, where come the "latitude" values from? If you have the values in the context of the `setCollection` method, you can add them like proposed in the answer. If you have the populated collection, you can sort the array ($productArray = $this->_collection->getData()) using `usort`: `usort($productArray, function ($a, $b){return ($a['latitude'] < $b['latitude']) ? -1 : 1;});` - but I guess we still don't know the whole story, so that might not work for whatever you expect :-)

Comment: yes,you're right that "data can be used everywhere where you use the collection data".i'm able to use on the phtml filenow just forget everything and my question is that how can i sort the product listing page based on this latitude value(latitude value is vary for each product and this is in numeric format)?please reply me.

Comment: I'm using  $this->_collection->setOrder("latitude DESC");  but it doesn't sort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code & let me know:

```
public function setCollection($collection)
    {

        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $mpJoinConditions = 'marketplace_product.mageproduct_id = e.entity_id';

       $this->_collection->getSelect()->join(
                $this->_collection->getTable('marketplace_product'),
                $mpJoinConditions,
                []
            )->columns("marketplace_product.seller_id")->where ("marketplace_product.store_id = '0'");

//add custom column
$this->_collection->getSelect()->columns(['latitude' => 1]);

             echo "<pre>" ; print_r($this->_collection->getData()) ; exit;
}
```

Comment: @wakar-ahmad Is this working ?

Comment: thanks for the reply,it's not working,getting some error.sorry my mistake 'latitude' value can be vary based on some calculation.

Comment: ok is it possible for you to return array instead of object from function ?
like: return $this->_collection->getData();

Comment: Actually i've to do sorting using "latitude" so i don't think so.

Comment: how you will add value to your latitude?

Comment: based on the seller_id i'll fetch from the table...actually i got the seller_id by joining the table...similerly i tried one more join to get the latitude value and it works but makes very havier category(more than 2K products) very.. slow so i decide to fetch latitude from custom query and set in the collection....i've posted same problem here:- https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/269417/49733

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92252/discussion-between-wakar-ahamad-and-hassan-ali-shahzad).

Comment: please give me the solution...

Comment: for that proper solution is you have to create product attribute 'latitude' the value of this attribute once update via shell script for all currently added products. For new products make sure this attribute updated whenever latitude added/updated in custom table against productid

Comment: no we can't create custom product attribute...we've to show nearest product to visitor first.so at run time we've to calculate the distance and sort accordingly.